# cakephp 1.3.6 exceeds memory limit on mamp server, but not on lamp server

Tags: php, cakephp, localhost

I've recently taken control of a large code base that was developed externally to my company. It is developed using cakephp but the version is old (1.3.6).

Using php5.3.29 on a lamp server, the app runs well. However when I run it on a mamp server using php5.3.29 I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in     /Library/WebServer/Documents/appy/cake/basics.php on line 415
```

[ Line 415 reads:

```
return (strpos(env('SCRIPT_URI'), 'https://') === 0);
```

]

as well as some strict standards warnings - which I don't believe to be related to the problem - but which nevertheless don't appear on the lamp server. I've tried increasing the amount of memory and the timeout, which I feel is a bad move, to no avail. I can't quite understand why this script would get into an infinite loop and eat up so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry, I fixed the issue.

Whilst the command line was indicating that I was using the correct php version, the html headers indicated otherwise. I managed to comment out some extra lines that were somehow added to the httpd.conf file that included loads of php5 modules to only include 5.3.29 which I had downloaded via brew.